# How to create a flat-file for a mongdb database and how to use that flat-file in elastic-search and kibana to query the data?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, kibana, flat-file

I am learning elastic-search and it's stack so I have a task assigned, first I need to create a flat-file of a MongoDB database that I have set up locally and then using that flat-file, I need to import that into kibana and query the database.
elastic-search and kibana are also hosted locally.

I don't know how to create a flat file and I just heard that word and googled what that is. I learned elastic-server query language but I don't know how to create an index using a flat-file in kibana or elastic-server.

I don't need some full explanation or steps, just some references to solutions will be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) to create either JSON or CSV format files from a MongoDB database.